# Customise PDF Download (Selected Pages or Sections before download)

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, merge, download

Would like to ask is it any possible way to customise pdf download like this:

https://axiata.com/investor-relations/2017/ar/customise-report.html

Like I say, it can be selected which pages or sections I want before I click on the download. I try to search from google or codepen also cant find any solutions. Much appreciate it if someone can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

quick update here. I found what I want with this:

https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/examples/downloader.html

Peace.